# Laravel view by time

Tags: laravel

I created a table with a datetime column, now I'm trying to display a table based on specific times, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work. I entered this code but the times are wrong they are not the ones I set, I have tried different ways but none have worked for the moment

Can anyone help me figure out why it's not working and how I can fix it?

```
$count1Hours = Post::query()
                    ->whereYear('time', Carbon::now()->year)
                    ->whereTime('time', '>=', Carbon::parse('07:00'))
                    ->whereTime('time', '<=', Carbon::parse('15:00'))
                    ->get();

Result:

16-03-2023 03:03 <-- there shouldn't be
01-01-2023 08:01
20-01-2023 01:01 <-- there shouldn't be
20-01-2023 02:01 <-- there shouldn't be
20-01-2023 03:01 <-- there shouldn't be
21-01-2023 07:01

$count2Hours = Post::query()
                    ->whereYear('time', Carbon::now()->year)
                    ->whereTime('time', '>=', Carbon::parse('15:00'))
                    ->whereTime('time', '<=', Carbon::parse('23:00'))
                    ->get();

$count3Hours = Post::query()
                    ->whereYear('time', Carbon::now()->year)
                    ->whereTime('time', '>=', Carbon::parse('23:00'))
                    ->whereTime('time', '<=', Carbon::parse('07:00'))
                    ->get();

column time --> datetime

2023-03-17 05:30:00
2023-03-17 00:55:00
2023-03-16 21:00:00
2023-03-16 18:00:00
2023-03-16 16:10:00
2023-03-16 15:00:00
2023-03-16 14:00:00
2023-03-16 12:00:00
2023-03-16 11:15:00
2023-03-16 09:00:00
2023-03-16 07:00:00
2023-03-16 06:22:00
2023-03-16 05:00:00
2023-03-15 00:30:00
2023-03-14 00:05:00
2023-03-13 00:00:00
2023-03-12 00:01:00
2023-03-11 00:00:00
2023-03-10 00:00:00
2023-03-09 00:00:00
2023-03-08 00:25:00
2023-03-07 00:00:00
```

Comment: how are you getting these results, `16-03-2023 03:03` is not a conventional format. Is the field 'time' of dateTime type? can you also share a sample of your database ?

Comment: Could it be a timezone issue i.e. your DB uses UTC but the result is then converted to another timezone or something like that?

Comment: yes the column is a datetime

Comment: how can i check this? I set up laravel for europe/rome

Comment: You can connect to the database directly and do `SELECT @@GLOBAL.time_zone` (if that says `SYSTEM` you can also do `SELECT @@GLOBAL.system_time_zone` and check that that says. Then query for some data on the database and check what the date shown is. MySQL should display dates/times using the time_zone variable. You can compare that value with what Laravel shows

Comment: i ran the command from phpmyadmin and it returns me the result: @@GLOBAL.time_zone
SYSTEM and :@@GLOBAL.system_time_zone
PDT

Comment: the server is setup with PST so i have to change settings in laravel to solve this problem? but to then fix the time zone I need how to do it?

Comment: https://laravel.io/forum/10-16-2015-set-default-mysql-timezone-on-connect looks like it has some reasonable solutions. In your case you could adjust to the timezone your app uses

Comment: thanks for the link, now i set the timezone as in the explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to match it with time format('H:i:s'). You can try something like this.

```
$count1Hours = Post::query()
                    ->whereYear('time', Carbon::now()->year)
                    ->whereTime('time', '>=', Carbon::parse('07:00')->format('H:i:s'))
                    ->whereTime('time', '<', Carbon::parse('15:00')->addSecond()->format('H:i:s'))
                    ->get();

$count2Hours = Post::query()
                    ->whereYear('time', Carbon::now()->year)
                    ->whereTime('time', '>=', Carbon::parse('15:00')->format('H:i:s'))
                    ->whereTime('time', '<', Carbon::parse('23:00')->addSecond()->format('H:i:s'))
                    ->get();

$count3Hours = Post::query()
                    ->whereYear('time', Carbon::now()->year)
                    ->where(function ($query) {
                        $query->whereTime('time', '>=', Carbon::parse('23:00')->format('H:i:s'))
                              ->orWhereTime('time', '<', Carbon::parse('07:00')->addSecond()->format('H:i:s'));
                    })
                    ->get();
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: I was hoping it would work but unfortunately it still doesn't work, the result is the same in all three results, all times are mixed up I don't understand why

Comment: Thanks your suggestion works, I had made a mistake in the model by inserting this code and it made all the results go wrong
   protected $casts = [
         'time' => 'datetime:d/m/Y'
     ];